# Computing surface area of a spherical patch

Tags: matlab, math

By using `surf2patch(sphere(),'triangle')`, the spherical coordinates of sphere are converted into triangular patches.

Is there any way of calculating the surface area of each one of these patches?

I can iterate through each patch, and obtain the cartesian coordinates of each of the vertices that form the patch, but not sure about the math part.

Thanks

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_triangle#Lines_and_angles_on_a_sphere

Comment: Or [this](http://planetmath.org/AreaOfASphericalTriangle.html).

Comment: I guess I wasn't googling with the right keywords. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This means that your triangles(polygones) are already in cartesian coordinates. I will suggest you to use the basic polygone command i.e. A = polyarea(X,Y). By this way you can iterate through all of your triangles and calculate the area of it.

Look at [this mathworks.com page](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/polyarea.html) for more help.

Comment: Would this compute the surface area of a spherical triangle though? Or the triangle that lies on the plane given by the 3 vertices?

Comment: This would give you surface area of the triangle. Personally, I would prefer to calculate it by writing my own program. A good discussion is given on this page of [maths fun](http://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/trig-area-triangle-without-right-angle.html) and is very easy to implement.  An implementation is available on [this page] (http://vision.ece.ucsb.edu/~zuliani/Code/Matlab/tri_area.html)